# Django: AttributeError: 'CustomUserManager' object has no attribute 'strip'

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am trying to create custom user model,  I created  `NewUser` and  `CustomUserManager` there is a problem  when I try to normalize email field in `CustomUserManager` it  gives the error above, I don't understand the reason behind this error.

models.py

```
from django.db import  models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser,PermissionsMixin, BaseUserManager


class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self,email,password,user_name,about,**other_fields):
     email=self.normalize_email(email); #here
     user=self.model(email=email,user_name=user_name,about=about)
     user.set_password(password)
     user.save()
     return user;


    def create_superuser(self, email,user_name,password,**other_fields):
            other_fields.setdefault('is_staff',True)
            other_fields.setdefault('is_superuser',True)
            other_fields.setdefault('is_active',True)

            if other_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
                raise ValueError('super  user must be assigned to is_staf= True')
            if other_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
                
                raise ValueError('Super user must be assigned to is_super_user=True')
            return self.create_user (self,email,user_name,password,**other_fields)   



class NewUser(AbstractBaseUser,PermissionsMixin):
    email=models.EmailField(unique=True)
    user_name=models.CharField(max_length=32,unique=True)
    about =models.CharField(max_length=512,blank=True)
    is_staff=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active=models.BooleanField(default=False) 
    objects=CustomUserManager();
    USERNAME_FIELD='email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS=['user_name']
```

Error

> line 25, in normalize_email   email_name, domain_part =
> email.strip().rsplit('@', 1)   AttributeError: 'CustomUserManager'
> object has no attribute 'strip'

Comment: I solved the problem  by just  stringifying  email  email=normalize_email(str(email), don't know what was causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem came from calling `self.create_user` with passing `self` as first argument in `create_superuser` method.

```py
def create_superuser(self, email, user_name, password, **other_fields):
    ...
    return self.create_user(self, email, user_name, password, **other_fields)
```

Removing it should fix the issue

```py
def create_superuser(self, email, user_name, password, **other_fields):
    ...
    return self.create_user(email, user_name, password, **other_fields)
```

Comment: I am not sure what exactly happens  in the  if we pass self as first argument

Comment: Since it's an instance method, you shouldn't have to pass `self` when calling it. Python use `self` to refer to an instance. In your case, if you pass `self` when calling `self.create_user` it's passed as an `email` argument, hence it raises the error since an instance `CustomUserManager` doesn't have a string method `strip`.

Comment: This is not a Django problem, but a python problem. You should look into the python class and instance method for better understanding.